# Verify files not in use before attempting to delete a folder on the network

Tags: vba, networking, delete-file

```vb
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
BazKlasor = "\\SRV01\l.urge\01 IS TAKIP\11 BAZ"
ArsivKlasor = "\\SRV01\l.urge\80 ARSIV\01 IS TAKIP\11 BAZ"

arsiveGonKlasor = BazKlasor & "\" & Me.FR15_cmb01.Value

If fso.folderexists(arsiveGonKlasor) Then
   fso.CopyFolder arsiveGonKlasor, ArsivKlasor & "\"
   fso.deletefolder arsiveGonKlasor
Else
   MsgBox Me.FR15_cmb01.Value & " KLASÖRÜ BULUNAMADI. İŞLEM SONLANDIRILIYOR", vbCritical, "L.URGE"
   Call sifrekapat
   Exit Sub
End If
```

I can delete a folder on the network with the code above.

If someone is working on the files in the folder, I get an error. How can I check this before I start deleting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to check whether someone is using a file in the folder, it would be simpler to use [error handling](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_error_handling.htm) to attempt deletion of the folder, catching the error and doing something useful if it fails. For example:

```vb
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler   ' Enable error-handling routine.

   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   BazKlasor = "\\SRV01\l.urge\01 IS TAKIP\11 BAZ"
   ArsivKlasor = "\\SRV01\l.urge\80 ARSIV\01 IS TAKIP\11 BAZ"

   arsiveGonKlasor = BazKlasor & "\" & Me.FR15_cmb01.Value

   If fso.folderexists(arsiveGonKlasor) Then
      fso.CopyFolder arsiveGonKlasor, ArsivKlasor & "\"
      fso.deletefolder arsiveGonKlasor
   Else
      MsgBox Me.FR15_cmb01.Value & " KLASÖRÜ BULUNAMADI. İŞLEM SONLANDIRILIYOR", vbCritical, "L.URGE"
      Call sifrekapat
      Exit Sub
   End If

   MsgBox "Delete worked!"

   Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:    ' Error-handling routine.
   MsgBox "Delete failed! Error: " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description

   'Do something useful here
```

Comment: You forgot to add an `Exit` statement before the `ErrorHandler` line, else it will always be called!

Comment: @Dean Thank you for pointing that out, I've corrected it now.